# How to fetch data in React Flux from either the store or server?

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

What is the best pattern to call a Flux store for some data and get it if it's there **or call the server if it's not**?

I see this mentioned at the bottom of [this article](https://madebymany.com/blog/beyond-the-to-do-app-writing-complex-applications-using-flux-react-js), quoting Ian Obermiller from Facebook, but I can't find an example of a store which has the logic to talk to the server when the data requested is missing from its cache.

I want to implement this approach on a project but my team says that it breaks the Flux pattern. Does anyone have experience with adding fetch logic to the stores and using the actions only for writes?

Answer (score 0):

When I've done this in the past, the pattern usually has gone something like the code below. Here are a few notes on that code:

`getDataFromAPI()` obviously is an HTTP request or something similar that returns a promise, which resolves with the data you want in the store. You could do this with callbacks, of course.

`storeDataInStore()` is a call to the Dispatcher, which handles the deposit of the data into the store.

The component listens for changes on the store, so when you call `getDataFromAPI()` and `storeDataInStore()` successively, the component will hear the change on the store, call the `handleStoreDataChange()` method, and re-render appropriately.

```
import LoadingComponent from './LoadingComponent';

import Store from '../../stores/ThatStore';
import { getDataFromAPI } from '../../utils/WebUtils';
import { storeDataInStore } from '../../utils/AppUtils';

class ThisComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    let dataFromStore = Store.getDataFromStore();
    if (/* condition indicating data is in store */) {
      this.setState(dataFromStore);
    } else if (/* condition indicating data is not in store */) {
      getDataFromAPI().then((data) => {
        storeDataInStore(data);
      });
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleStoreDataChange = this.handleStoreDataChange.bind(this);
    Store.addChangeListener(this.handleStoreDataChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Store.removeChangeListener(this.handleStoreDataChange);
  }

  handleStoreDataChange() {
    this.setState(Object.assign(Store.getDataFromStore());
  }

  render() {
    if (/* condition indicating that you are awaiting data */) return <LoadingComponent />;
    return (
      /* All of the things you would render if the data is loaded in the store */
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm.. isn't the point of using stores to separate data fetches/retrievals from the component that uses that data?